# How to render a link in root page, but not in authenticated_root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this partial :

```
<%= image_tag('logo.png', class: 'logo') %> 

<%= link_to "Facebook Sign In", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: 'facebook', style: " text-decoration:none" if current_page? root_path %>
```

Which renders a logo always, and should render the link only if the page is the root(the non authenticated root, I have 2 roots), but it's also rendering the link even if the page is  authenticated_root . How do I restrict the link to be rendered in root but not in authenticated_root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than path i would say you should link to the controller and action.

like so (assuming your non authenticated root is at home#index)

```
<%= link_to "Facebook Sign In", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: 'facebook', style: " text-decoration:none" if params[:controller].eql?('home') && params[:action].eql?('index') %>
```

Comment: Wonderful, didn't know I can use controller and action. Accepting soon.